# Getting error clicking on button "EXCEPTION: Error during evaluation of "click" "

Tags: angular

Component:

```
import {Component , EventEmitter} from 'angular2/core';
import {fixedHeader} from '../header/fixed-header.component.ts';
import {FooterComponent} from '../footer/footer.component.ts';
import {FORM_PROVIDERS, FormBuilder, Validators} from 'angular2/common';
import {HttpService} from "./http-service.ts";

import {ControlMessages} from './control-messages.component.ts';
import {ValidationService} from './validation_service.ts';

import {Http} from "angular2/http";
import {Observable} from "rxjs/Observable";
import 'rxjs/Rx';
import {Headers} from "angular2/http";

@Component({
    selector:'registration-component'
    directives:[fixedHeader, FooterComponent , ControlMessages],
    providers: [HttpService],
    template:`
<fixed-header></fixed-header>   
<form [ngFormModel]="userForm">  

<div class="container" id="wrap">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-6 col-md-offset-3">
                    <br><br>
                    <legend><b>Client Personal Details:</b></legend>
                        <div class="row">
                            <div class="col-xs-6 col-md-3">
                                <h4>   Client Name:</h4>
                            </div>
                            <div class="col-xs-6 col-md-8">
                                <input type="text" id="fullname"  class="form-control input-lg" placeholder="Full Name"  ngControl="fullname" #fullname/> 
                            </div>
                            <div class="col-xs-6 col-md-1">
                                <control-messages control="fullname"></control-messages>
                            </div>  
                        </div>
                        <button class="btn btn-lg btn-success btn-block signup-btn" 
        [disabled]="!userForm.valid" 
        (click) ="saveUser(fullname.value)" >
    Create Account
</button>
                        <br><br>
            </div>
        </div>            
    </div> 
</form> 
<footer-component></footer-component>
    `   
})


export class RegistrationComponent
{   
    response : string;
    userForm: any;
    constructor(
      private _formBuilder: FormBuilder) {

        this.userForm = this._formBuilder.group({
          'fullname': ['', Validators.required],

      });
    }

    constructor(private _httpService: HttpService) {}

    saveUser( fullname : string)
            {
                const data = {
                            fullname : fullname
                };

                    this._httpService.createPost(data)
                        .subscribe(
                            data => this.response = data, 
                            error => console.log(error)
                        );
            }

}
```

Service:

```
import {Injectable} from 'angular2/core';
import {Http , Headers , RequestOptions} from "angular2/http";
import {Observable} from "rxjs/Observable";
import 'rxjs/Rx';

@Injectable()
export class HttpService {
    constructor(private _http: Http) {}

    createPost(data:any)
    {
        const body = JSON.stringify(data);
        const headers = new Headers();
        headers.append('Content-Type', 'application/json');
        return this._http.post('storeSignUpData/', body, {
                headers: headers
                })
                //.map(res => res.json().data);
                .catch(this.handleError)
    }

    private handleError (error: any) {
        console.error("Error");
        console.error(error);
    }

}

main.ts


   import {bootstrap}        from 'angular2/platform/browser';
import {AppComponent}     from './app.component.ts';
import {HTTP_PROVIDERS , JSONP_PROVIDERS} from "angular2/http";
import {provide} from 'angular2/core';
import {ROUTER_PROVIDERS, LocationStrategy, HashLocationStrategy} from 'angular2/router';
import {FORM_PROVIDERS, FormBuilder, Validators} from 'angular2/common';
bootstrap(
        AppComponent, [
                         ROUTER_PROVIDERS , FORM_PROVIDERS , HTTP_PROVIDERS , JSONP_PROVIDERS ,
                         provide(
                                 LocationStrategy, {useClass: HashLocationStrategy}
                                 )
                         ]
        );


Error:
```

> ```
>      angular2.dev.js:23501 EXCEPTION: Error during evaluation of "submit"BrowserDomAdapter.logError @
> ```
>
> angular2.dev.js:23501BrowserDomAdapter.logGroup @
>   angular2.dev.js:23512ExceptionHandler.call @
>   angular2.dev.js:1185(anonymous function) @
>   angular2.dev.js:12489NgZone._notifyOnError @
>   angular2.dev.js:13533collection_1.StringMapWrapper.merge.onError @
>   angular2.dev.js:13437Zone.run @ angular2-polyfills.js:1247(anonymous
>   function) @ angular2.dev.js:13456NgZone.run @
>   angular2.dev.js:13418outsideHandler @ angular2.dev.js:13253Zone.run @
>   angular2-polyfills.js:1243zoneBoundFn @ angular2-polyfills.js:1220
>               angular2.dev.js:23501 ORIGINAL EXCEPTION: TypeError: Cannot read property 'createPost' of
>   undefinedBrowserDomAdapter.logError @
>   angular2.dev.js:23501ExceptionHandler.call @
>   angular2.dev.js:1194(anonymous function) @
>   angular2.dev.js:12489NgZone._notifyOnError @
>   angular2.dev.js:13533collection_1.StringMapWrapper.merge.onError @
>   angular2.dev.js:13437Zone.run @ angular2-polyfills.js:1247(anonymous
>   function) @ angular2.dev.js:13456NgZone.run @
>   angular2.dev.js:13418outsideHandler @ angular2.dev.js:13253Zone.run @
>   angular2-polyfills.js:1243zoneBoundFn @ angular2-polyfills.js:1220
>       angular2.dev.js:23501 ORIGINAL STACKTRACE:

Getting error while posting data to server. I dont know what is going wrong. guys any idea ..

Comment: It would be a lot easier for you and people reading the answer if you'd reduce you example to the minimum that's necessary to reprocude the problem. Does the problem really only occur if you form has ~20 controls? How many can you remove while still getting the error?

Comment: Did you add `HttpService` to providers somewhere (bootstrap, root component, ...)? If yes, how does the code look like exactly?

Comment: yes , its included , GET method is working properly , but for posting data its giving error.

Answer (score 0):

Your error is pretty clear

```
EXCEPTION: TypeError: Cannot read property 'createPost' of undefined
```

That means that `this._httpService` is undefined.

The only thing I can see is the mix of single and double quotes in your imports, you should change them all to be single quotes.

For example your faulty line is this one using double quotes (among the other ones that are using double quotes)

```
import {HttpService} from "./http-service.ts";
```

You should change it to use single quotes

```
import {HttpService} from './http-service.ts';
```

And probably the ones you have inside your service are causing troubles too.

This is an issue being tracked in this [issue](https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/7433) in angular2's repo, and answered in this [issue](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/7616) in TypeScript's repo.

**Edit**

The above comment is still valid, but I just saw what I think (again) is your problem

You have two constructors

```
constructor(
  private _formBuilder: FormBuilder) {
   // ...
}

constructor(private _httpService: HttpService) {}
```

Keep one of them

```
constructor(private _formBuilder: FormBuilder, private _httpService: HttpService) {
   // ...
}
```

Comment: I changed to single quote but getting same error .. thanks for reply